# What is wrong part in my Android code with ffmpeg?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to get mixed video.(Image + Video)
   Total duration of original video is 180 sec. I want to put image to the front of video. So, I made some code in android studio. 
  But I can not look any toast. 
What is wrong ? How to check the end of process?

...
**path = "libray folder";**
...

```
    private class ProcessVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                Process ffmpegProcess = null;

                try {
          // initialize command for process video
              // library is video process library.
                    String[] command ={path,"-i", input, "-r", "1", "-q:v", "2", "-f", "image", input};


                    ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();

                    OutputStream ffmpegOutStream = ffmpegProcess.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));

                    String line;

                    Log.v(THISTAG,"***Starting FFMPEG***");
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
// in progress 
                        Log.v(THISTAG,"***"+line+"***");
                    }
// finish all process
                    Log.v(THISTAG,"***Ending FFMPEG***");
                    videoProcessFinishFlag = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (ffmpegProcess != null) {
                    ffmpegProcess.destroy();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void... result) {
// show result
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VideoEditorActivity.this, "Done Processing Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed some parameters.
Try this :
String[] Command ={path,"-y","-i", input,"-strict","experimental", "-r", "1", "-q:v", "2", "-f", "image", input};
Above command there are two "input", then they are different each other. 
first parameter : video path
second parameter : image file path
Right? This command take a few long times to process video, I think.
Thank you for your commitment.

Comment: Then do you know ffmpeg well ? I am very interested in your answer.

Comment: And then jim22 , I have more questions.

Comment: Do you want to answer my more  question?